# Tinymce formatting issue in chrome : paste_retain_style_properties : "all" working in IE but not in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

My dot net web application is using Tinymce editor to get text from the user. Now the text pasted retains the exact formatting in IE but in chrome extra empty paragraphs are added after every para so basically there are two three empty lines between each actual para in the document I am generating thought the application after parsing the raw html

I am using the latest version of editor and below are the init files details:

```
tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "specific_textareas",
            'force_br_newlines': true,
            'force_p_newlines': false,
            'forced_root_block': false,
            editor_selector: "rich_text_editor_coi",
            plugin: "paste"
    });
```

Is there any setting or way I can retain the source formatting in chrome as well

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this happening?

Comment: I did some more analysis and it seems paste_retain_style_properties : "all" is not working in chrome. When this is set, it works in IE but not in chrome. The problem is in formatting and also with list which it shows not supported. Even though I am using paste plugin